# How to change position of labels on top of plots by using hvPlot

Tags: python, hvplot

By using hvplot.labels() with `text_align='left'`,
I could change the label position to right like this:

```
import hvplot.pandas 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'City': ['Buenos Aires', 'Brasilia', 'Santiago', 'Bogota', 'Caracas'],
     'Country': ['Argentina', 'Brazil', 'Chile', 'Colombia', 'Venezuela'],
     'Latitude': [-34.58, -15.78, -33.45, 4.60, 10.48],
     'Longitude': [-58.66, -47.91, -70.66, -74.08, -66.86]})
df.hvplot.points(x='Longitude', y='Latitude', padding=0.2, hover_cols='all', width=300) * \
df.hvplot.labels(x='Longitude', y='Latitude', text='City', 
text_align='left', hover=False).opts(text_font_size='7pt')
```

[image]

But the labels still overlap with the round marks, so I want to shift them more to the right.  How can I get the following diagram? For now, the only way I can think of is to add a space at the beginning of the label...

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the last line, within `opts()`, you can add `xoffset=0.7` and that should move the labels to the right. Updated code and plot below.

```
import hvplot.pandas 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'City': ['Buenos Aires', 'Brasilia', 'Santiago', 'Bogota', 'Caracas'],
     'Country': ['Argentina', 'Brazil', 'Chile', 'Colombia', 'Venezuela'],
     'Latitude': [-34.58, -15.78, -33.45, 4.60, 10.48],
     'Longitude': [-58.66, -47.91, -70.66, -74.08, -66.86]})
df.hvplot.points(x='Longitude', y='Latitude', padding=0.2, hover_cols='all', width=300) * \
df.hvplot.labels(x='Longitude', y='Latitude', text='City', 
text_align='left', hover=False).opts(xoffset=0.7, text_font_size='7pt')
```

**Output plot**

[image]

Comment: `xoffset=0.7` means that we can change the position based on the coordinates of the x-axis. This is excellent. Thanks a lot!